# QuerySnapshot using FirebaseFirestore is not accessing the right collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In this code I have used Future builder to update the search screen with the search results but code shows the error of:
StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)

I debugged the program and found that the QuerySnapshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjmR1.png)is taking the wrong collection hence it could not find the field photoUrl in it.It should take the users collection instead it takes the posts collection. Please go through the code and help me with this.

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .where("username",
                      isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchController.text)
                  .get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }

                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]["photourl"],
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]["username"],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            )
```

[This is the image of the emulator on which I ran the code without debugging and this the error I got but one of the result was shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdaAR.png)

[While Debugging I found that the snap contains the query snapshot which is of posts collection. I have written users in the collection argument.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjmR1.png)

[In this image you can see that the posts collection has all the fields as shown in the debugged window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw2HI.png)

[This is the image of the users collection which I am trying to access . It has different fields than the ones shown in the debugged window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUZnD.png)

Comment: I've never seen Firestore access another collection than what your code tells it to access. How would it know about that other collection if not through your code? Can you edit your question to include more information about what led you to this conclusion?

Comment: I couldn't understand it myself please go through the images i have uploaded .

Comment: Could it be that one of your user documents contains the wrong data? To debug this, print the document ID with `(snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index].id` and look up that user document in the Firebase console.